# Migrate relational table to Redis

Tags: redis

Currently, I have a system that record records at oracle database, a specific table. I'm want change to Redis, but I'm with some doubts.

Field's table:

```
BRAS_INTERFACE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No      1   
CLVAN   NUMBER(10,0)    No      2   
NAS_IDENTIFIER  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  No      3   
NAS_IP_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   No      4   
SVLAN   NUMBER(10,0)    No      5   
FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   Yes     6   
CLASS   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     7   
MAC_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     8   
PROFILE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     9   
TIME_STAMP  TIMESTAMP(6)    Yes     10  
TYPE_TICKET VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     11  
SMART_INTERFACE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     12  
CVLAN   NUMBER(10,0)    Yes     13
```

Constraint's table:

```
"BRAS_INTERFACE" IS NOT NULL
"CLVAN" IS NOT NULL
"NAS_IDENTIFIER" IS NOT NULL
"NAS_IP_ADDRESS" IS NOT NULL
"SVLAN" IS NOT NULL
```

The table keep PPPoE sessions, when a subscriber go to up, then insert a record, when a subscriber go to down, then delete a record, both cases, the fields: BRAS_INTERFACE, CLVAN, NAS_IDENTIFIER, NAS_IP_ADDRESS and SVLAN useds as constraint.

I do querys at table by constraints or by any another field.

With Redis how I can to do some thing like relational table?

Comment: Redis is a key-value storage, not relational. So you need to have a key for each query you want to do. It's better to have your queries in order to help you...

Answer (score 0):

If you have questions about what Redis can do I would think you should look at the vendor site: https://redis.io/topics/introduction.  Oracle and SQL Server both support in-memory tables by the way.